# Impute missing data, while forcing correlation coefficient to remain the same

Tags: python, r, matlab, julia

Consider the following (excel) dataset:

```
m   |   r
----|------
2.0 | 3.3
0.8 |   
    | 4.0
1.3 |   
2.1 | 5.2
    | 2.3
    | 1.9
2.5 | 
1.2 | 3.0
2.0 | 2.6
```

**My goal is to fill in missing values using the following condition:**

> Denote as R the pairwise correlation between the above two columns (around 0.68). Denote as R* the correlation **after** the empty cells have been filled in. **Fill in the table so that (R - R*)^2 = 0**. This is, I want to keep the correlation structure of the data intact.

So far I have done it using Matlab:

```
clear all;

m = xlsread('data.xlsx','A2:A11') ;
r = xlsread('data.xlsx','B2:B11') ;

rho = corr(m,r,'rows','pairwise');

x0 = [1,1,1,1,1,1];
lb = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
f = @(x)my_correl(x,rho);

SOL = fmincon(f,x0,[],[],[],[],lb)
```

where the function `my_correl` is:

```
function X = my_correl(x,rho)

sum_m = (11.9 + x(1) + x(2) + x(3));
sum_r = (22.3 + x(1) + x(2) + x(3));
avg_m = (11.9 + x(1) + x(2) + x(3))/8;
avg_r = (22.3 + x(4) + x(5) + x(6))/8;
rho_num = 8*(26.32 + 4*x(1) + 2.3*x(2) + 1.9*x(3) + 0.8*x(4) + 1.3*x(5) + 2.5*x(6)) - sum_m*sum_r;
rho_den = sqrt(8*(22.43 + (4*x(1))^2 + (2.3*x(2))^2 + (1.9*x(3))^2) - sum_m^2)*sqrt(8*(78.6 + (0.8*x(4))^2 + (1.3*x(5))^ + (2.5*x(6))^2) - sum_r^2);

X = (rho - rho_num/rho_den)^2;

end
```

This function computes the correlation manually, where every missing data is a variable `x(i)`.

**The problem: my actual dataset has more than 20,000 observations.** There is no way I can create that rho formula manually.

**How can I fill in my dataset?**

Note 1: I am open to use alternative languages like Python, Julia, or R. Matlab it's just my default one.

Note 2: a 100 points bounty will be awarded to the answer. Promise from now.

Comment: @luchonacho, you already have your answer below but in the future, if you have a more complicated dataset, with more columns, perhaps you can consider the `Amelia` package. Please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47247/multiple-imputation-with-the-amelia-package for more information about this package. The imputed dataset will not have exactly the same correlation as the incomplete dataset, but it should be close given that Amelia assumes the full dataset follows a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: As per previous comment, this looks in general like a multiple imputation problem, with packages like Amelia, mice, mi and probably others performing similar functionality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I would approach it, with an implementation in R provided:

There is not a unique solution for imputing the missing data points, such that the pairwise correlation of the complete (imputed) data is equal to the pairwise correlation of the incomplete data. So to find a 'good' solution rather than just 'any' solution, we can introduce an additional criteria that the complete imputed data should also share the same linear regression with the original data.  This leads us to a fairly simple approach.

1. calculate a linear regression model for the original data.
2. find the imputed values for missing values that would lie exactly on this regression line.
3. generate a random scatter of residuals for the imputed values around this regression line
4. scale the imputed residuals to force the correlation of the complete imputed data to be equal to that of the original data

A solution like this in R:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)

rho = cor(dt$m,dt$r,'pairwise')

# calculate linear regression of original data
fit1 = lm(r ~ m, data=dt)
fit2 = lm(m ~ r, data=dt)
# extract the standard errors of regression intercept (in each m & r direction)
# and multiply s.e. by sqrt(n) to get standard deviation 
sd1 = summary(fit1)$coefficients[1,2] * sqrt(dt[!is.na(r), .N])
sd2 = summary(fit2)$coefficients[1,2] * sqrt(dt[!is.na(m), .N])

# find where data points with missing values lie on the regression line
dt[is.na(r), r.imp := coefficients(fit1)[1] + coefficients(fit1)[2] * m] 
dt[is.na(m), m.imp := coefficients(fit2)[1] + coefficients(fit2)[2] * r]

# generate randomised residuals for the missing data, using the s.d. calculated above
dt[is.na(r), r.ran := rnorm(.N, sd=sd1)] 
dt[is.na(m), m.ran := rnorm(.N, sd=sd2)] 

# function that scales the residuals by a factor x, then calculates how close correlation of imputed data is to that of original data
obj = function(x, dt, rho) {
  dt[, r.comp := r][, m.comp := m]
  dt[is.na(r), r.comp := r.imp + r.ran*x] 
  dt[is.na(m), m.comp := m.imp + m.ran*x] 
  rho2 = cor(dt$m.comp, dt$r.comp,'pairwise')
  (rho-rho2)^2
}

# find the value of x that minimises the discrepencay of imputed versus original correlation
fit = optimize(obj, c(-5,5), dt, rho)

x=fit$minimum
dt[, r.comp := r][, m.comp := m]
dt[is.na(r), r.comp := r.imp + r.ran*x] 
dt[is.na(m), m.comp := m.imp + m.ran*x] 
rho2 = cor(dt$m.comp, dt$r.comp,'pairwise')
(rho-rho2)^2  # check that rho2 is approximately equal to rho
```

As a final check, calculate linear regression of the complete imputed data
and plot to show that regression line is same as for original data.  Note that the plot below was for the large data set shown below, to demonstrate use of this method on large data.

```
fit.comp = lm(r.comp ~ m.comp, data=dt)
plot(dt$m.comp, dt$r.comp)
points(dt$m, dt$r, col="red")
abline(fit1, col="green")
abline(fit.comp, col="blue")
mtext(paste(" Rho =", round(rho,5)), at=-1)
mtext(paste(" Rho2 =", round(rho2, 5)), at=6)
```

[image]

**DATA**

original toy data from OP example:

```
dt=structure(list(m = c(2, 0.8, NA, 1.3, 2.1, NA, NA, 2.5, 1.2, 2), 
                  r = c(3.3, NA, 4, NA, 5.2, 2.3, 1.9, NA, 3, 2.6)), 
             .Names = c("m", "r"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
             class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

A larger data set to demonstrate on big data

```
dt = data.table(m=rnorm(1e5, 3, 2))[, r:=1.5 + 1.1*m + rnorm(1e5,0,2)]
dt[sample(.N, 3e4), m:=NA]
dt[sample(which(!is.na(m)), 3e4), r := NA]
```

Comment: This is very clever! Of course, you can see correlation as nothing else than a linear regression. Now, I have three columns, so an alternative would be to run this for each pair separately, and then combine them. I also have bounds, which if I store as vector, could use to limit the stochastic error. I will give it a try and come back.

Comment: One note I should add: I used the standard error of the regression intercept to provide the initial estimate of the s.d. of residuals. This works fine for the small toy data example you gave, and provides an initial guess for the optimization that is close the solution.  With large data the standard error and standard deviation will differ more, so you should probably use `sd = se* sqrt(N)` for large data.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to use standard errors at all. **Why one random draw and not another?** In that case, the better way to do it would be to run many many iterations of random errors, and average the final series, but then you will end up in the regression line anyway! Just like in standard OLS, your best individual prediction is by definition the conditional mean. **If the correlation holds with scaled normal standard errors, it should hold without errors.** That is the point of the linear regression as correlation. I will confirm this. I'm doing it with Stata.

Comment: The requirement to use the error estimates is to ensure proportionality between  the spread of points in each of the m and r directions. You do not want to have imputed values for m to have the same size residuals in the m direction as  the imputed r values have in the r direction.  Also, it is nice to have the initial estimate of points close to the final solution, to ease optimization

Comment: Mmm, it seems your method for standard errors is necessary. Otherwise I get super high correlations.

Comment: I edited to use s.d. rather than standard errors for the initial values.  Also added an extra check at the end to show that the linear regression of complete data is the same as the original data.

Comment: Added some comments in script to make it easier for non-R programmers to follow