# Determine dataset that was used to generate an lm() model

Tags: r, linear-regression

Lets say I was provided a multiple linear regression model such as:
y = B0 + B1x1 + B2x2

And **given** the intercept/coef values of this model:
B0 = 0.005275169B1
B1 = 0.067347131
B2 = -0.207909721

BUT.. I don't have the **original** dataset (x/y values) that generated that model. Is there anyway to generate a **new** dataset, then feed it into lm() where resulting lm()$coef call would then spit out the same BO, B1, B2 values noted above? In summary, I want to generate a dataset that when fed into lm() produces a model with 100% exact same coef as above.

Comment: This is a somewhat odd (or perhaps oddly phrased) question. Are you perhaps looking for `predict`? Once you have your model, you can generate new data consisting of predicted responses based on any values of your predictors variables. If you then fit the same model to your new data, you will obtain the same parameter of your model (but different sds).

Comment: There was an interesting comment here before by @markus on [Anscombe's Quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) which regrettably was removed. I advise having a read.

Comment: [continued] Anscombe's Quartet demonstrates how knowing summary statistics (e.g. mean, variance, regression coefficients) can be meaningless if the structure of residuals is ignored. In other words, you may have parameter estimates from a model which are *not* uniquely providing insight into the underlying data probability distribution.

Comment: Maybe something like this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39622066/2761575

Comment: So here is kind of what I'm looking for (if possible)..something like: give_me_dataframe_of_x_y_values(coef=c(2,10,7)), then if I call lm() using the x/y values generated from give_me_dataframe_of_x_y() the resulting lm()$coef would = 2, 10, 7. If this makes no sense and just isn't possible let me know.

Comment: You could do it, but it wouldn't be of much value as the errors would be entirely artificial (or even zero in the simplest case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment above, here is an example using the `mtcars` dataset, where we fit a linear model of the form `mpg = beta0 + beta1 * disp`.

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
summary(fit)
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
#
#Residuals:
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
#-4.8922 -2.2022 -0.9631  1.6272  7.2305
#
#Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept) 29.599855   1.229720  24.070  < 2e-16 ***
#disp        -0.041215   0.004712  -8.747 9.38e-10 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 3.251 on 30 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.7183,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.709
#F-statistic: 76.51 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 9.38e-10
```

We generate some new data for `disp` and use the model coefficients to predict a response for `mpg`.

```
df <- data.frame(disp = seq(1, 1000, length.out = 20))
df$mpg <- predict(fit, newdata = df)
```

We now fit the same model to the new data.

```
fit.new <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = df)
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = df)
#
#Residuals:
#       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max
#-1.720e-14 -3.095e-15  1.302e-15  3.618e-15  5.719e-15
#
#Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)  2.960e+01  2.235e-15  1.325e+16   <2e-16 ***
#disp        -4.122e-02  3.819e-18 -1.079e+16   <2e-16 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 5.178e-15 on 18 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:      1,    Adjusted R-squared:      1
#F-statistic: 1.165e+32 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
#
#Warning message:
#In summary.lm(fit.new) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

Notice how estimates are identical (but standard deviations and t statistics are not!). Also notice the warning at the bottom of the second model fit.

---

### Update

If you have coefficients `beta0` and `beta1` simply calculate the response as

```
beta0 <- coef(fit)[1]
beta1 <- coef(fit)[2]
df <- data.frame(disp = seq(1, 1000, length.out = 20))
df$mpg <- beta0 + df$disp * beta1
```

Comment: In your example, the initial dataset was created with mtcars and saved into an lm object. However in my case I cant create an initial lm() model because I don't have any data. I ONLY have the provided BO, B1, B2 coef values provided to me via pen/paper. I need a way to create a dataset (like mtcars in your example) that when I fit an lm() to it gives me those original BO, B1, B2 coef values in the lm() summary.

Comment: And sorry, you are right this is an odd question. Its just part of a school assignment, so maybe I am not asking correctly. I just want to somehow create a dataset of x/y values that I can feed into lm() to create a model with those same coef that were provided.

Comment: @JD1 It's the same if you have coefficients (see my updated answer); simply calculate the response as `beta0 + beta1 * x1 + beta2 * x2` once you've generated some numbers for `x1` and `x2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `model` field in the lm object.  Here's a reproducible example

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)    
newdata <- fit$model
#                      mpg  disp
# Mazda RX4           21.0 160.0
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 160.0
# Datsun 710          22.8 108.0
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4 258.0
# Hornet Sportabout   18.7 360.0
# Valiant             18.1 225.0
# ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an existing dataset like mtcars to run lm() on. I only have the provided coef values for B0, B1, B2 (provided on paper). I want to CREATE a dataset of x/y values that when fed into lm() will give me a model having those same B0, B1, B2 coef that were provided on paper. If that's even possible...

Comment: No problem - I misunderstood your question.  I thought you had been provided with the lm object itself.  I can leave this answer here anyway in case some other passer-by finds it useful